# Why Is HardHat Mainnet Fork Always Behind By Roughly 5 Blocks?

Tags: hardhat, testing, mainnet

Whenever I do a fork on mainnet at latest with hardhat, it's never at the latest block. Why is that? For example in the below:

```
    console.log("BLOCK FRO ALCHEMY: ", (await alchemyEthProvider.getBlock("latest")).number); //block N
    console.log("BLOCK FROM HARDHAT", (await hardhatProvider.getBlock("latest")).number); //block N-5
```

The hardhat settings for mainnet forking just uses the same provider as `alchemyEthProvider` above, so it's sourced from the same provider, ultimately. But for some reason, forking is a bit slower.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple key factors here:

- you're forking "from" mainnet, not on it
- a data/code "fork" is just like a fork in the road; one continues to the left and another to the right

This is why the fork cannot match mainnet, because it's now a completely different road and is effectively its own network.

Comment: this is not exactly true. if he forks latest block, then the hardhat's and mainnet's heads are equal, until either the local network or mainnet is altered